# IF OR AND excel formula with multiple output

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to write an if or and excel formula which will return a statement and the statement can be from 4 categories.

I have two variables and in order to return a statement the two parameters need to be satisfied.

The current formula i am using is as per below:

```
=IF(OR(AND(D4>1799,E4>"07:59"),AND(D4>900,E4>"05:59"),AND(D4>350,E4>"04:59"),AND(D4>0,E4>"07:59")),"Red","Amber")
```

However I am missing 2 other output "Green" and "Yellow"

can someone help me please?

Comment: Does that actually work? Those text-that-look-like-time tell me it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by *'I am missing 2 other output "Green" and "Yellow"'*, what do you plan to do with them?

Comment: `"Red"` is displayed if the `OR/AND` condition evaluates to TRUE, `"Amber"` if it's FALSE.  You need to replace `"Amber"` with another set of conditions that will turn it `"Amber"` if TRUE - leaving a FALSE for another set of conditions if it's `"Green"` - after those have been evaluated it will be `"Yellow"` if still false.  `IF(<Conditions>,"Red", IF(<Conditions>,"Amber", IF(<Conditions>,"Green","Yellow")))`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - I have two parameters in order to return for example "red"  I can still use your formula an input if(and<condition.,"Red",...) correct?

Comment: @Jeeped - it worked for amber only but one of the parameters is time I think it wouldn't work as it should be